# PostgreSQL unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns

Tags: postgresql, table-partitioning

I want to create a partitioned table in the PostgreSQL database and run the below query.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tracking_trackingdata (

  "id"                  uuid                     NOT NULL,
  tracking_id           varchar(100)             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  dynamic_url_object_id bigint                   NOT NULL,
  ip_address            inet                     NOT NULL,
  scan_time             timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  created               timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  modified              timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY ( "id", scan_time )

) PARTITION BY RANGE ( scan_time )
```

but it keeps on giving the error

> [`0A000`] ERROR: unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns Detail: `UNIQUE` constraint on table `tracking_trackingdata` lacks column `scan_time` which is part of the partition key.

The `scan_time` could be duplicated while the `id` column will always be unique. I want to have a partition by `scan_time`, how can I apply a unique constraint on it when there can be duplicate entries at the same time? I have also passed the `id` and `scan_time` columns to the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint so that the combination of both will always be unique.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory - what part of it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: The `scan_time` could be duplicated while the `id` column will always be unique. I want to have a partition by `scan_time`, how can I apply a unique constraint on it when there can be duplicate entries at the same time? I have also passed the `id` and `scan_time` columns to the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint so that the combination of both will always be unique.

Comment: It looks like you need to clarify what you need to be unique. Your statement *"`id` column will always be unique"* is contradicted by your `PRIMARY KEY ( "id", scan_time )` definition: the latter allows for multiple entries of the exact same `"id"` as long as they come with different `scan_time`. The answer you accepted also pretty much breaks your `tracking_id` uniqueness: you attempted to define it as globally unique, while the proposed constraint enables duplicates as long as there's even a nanosecond `scan_time` difference between twin entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading: the problem isn't your `PRIMARY KEY`, it's the `UNIQUE` constraint on your `tracking_id` column;

...so if you remove the `UNIQUE` constraint from the `tracking_id` then the `CREATE TABLE` statement succeeds: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h4UAZj25KSCS4eKHmFc89x/0

You can still require `tracking_id` to be unique, just promote the `UNIQUE` constraint from a single-column to a multi-column constraint. The docs explain why:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS

> To create a `unique` or `primary key` constraint on a partitioned table, the partition keys must not include any expressions or function calls and the constraint's columns must include all of the partition key columns. This limitation exists because the individual indexes making up the constraint can only directly enforce uniqueness within their own partitions; therefore, the partition structure itself must guarantee that there are not duplicates in different partitions.

e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHj8XDJyZevcey7A2abiP8/0

This works for me, without errors, in Postgres 15:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tracking_trackingdata 
(
  "id"                  uuid                     NOT NULL,
  tracking_id           varchar(100)             NOT NULL,
  dynamic_url_object_id bigint                   NOT NULL,
  ip_address            inet                     NOT NULL,
  scan_time             timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  created               timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  modified              timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT PK_tracking_trackingdata PRIMARY KEY ( "id", scan_time ),
  CONSTRAINT UK_tracking_id UNIQUE ( tracking_id, scan_time )
  
) PARTITION BY RANGE ( scan_time );
```